# Why doesn't my counting loop work when searching a phrase in a file?

Tags: python, for-loop, count

I was looking to find how many times the phrase "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" shows up in a file and couldn't figure out why my code wasn't working.
I needed to strip the file to only show the lines that contained that phrase, and, in addition, count how many times that phrase shows up.
My code was able to strip it properly, but did not count the amount of times the phrase showed up. If anyone could help me figure out what I did wrong with my code that would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have an extra space in your checker for loop: "X-DSPAM-Confidence: ". Also, you are able to do this inside one for loop as the second one is somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just with one loop

```
count = 0
f = open("")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in f:
    if line.startwith(""): 
        print(line)
        count = count + 1
```